# How to run CouchbaseBackupRestore only once

Tags: kubernetes, couchbase, flux, kustomize

I define a CoucbaseBackupRestore resource for my kubernetes cluster. Managed with flux and kustomize (gitops)
The restore goes well. But when it is finished it starts another restore.
I want it to run only once.
Is it possible to tell kubernetes to not recreate a pod when the first one succeeds?

I have to comment out my CouchbaseBackupRestore resource in my kustomize file when the job succeeds.
But this is not a viable option for production.
BackoffLimit is not a solution either, as I want it to retry if it fails.

Thanks for tour help

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the Operator will garbage collect successful restore jobs. The expected behaviour is that the restore yaml would only be applied when a restore job is required.

This causes repeat creation in workflows like this; however, we've opened a ticket to track this request! https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/K8S-3121